# Temporary Database for Form Recovery in a Multi Step Form

Tags: reactjs

I'm an api developer who works at a company looking to move from a large CMS to a React web front end framework.

I've been given a new requirement that all multi page forms on our website should be restartable going forward and I have to solution design something for this.

Lets take the following example...

```
Form 1 - Select your product
Form 2 - Enter your details
Form 3 - Enter Payment details
```

The way I see it working is that the the first field on the form would be your email address. From there one for every next button click in the multi step form (i.e. after submission of each step) I'm thinking maybe the form fields get added to the session and maybe on session timeout if the form has not been submitted an api is called to persist those bits of the form that have already been submitted into DynamoDB using email address as an identifier.

That means if I had an incomplete form and come back, when I enter me email address it might be able to pick up my persisted data from DynamoDB.

I'd like to get some thoughts on this solution from the Reactjs developers. And if this has been done previously by others I'd love to hear your ideas on alternatives.

thanks

Comment: Is it a requirement that the data be persisted on the server too?

Comment: at this stage the requirement is to persist to DynamoDB. What extra value would you get from persisting on the server over DynamoDB?

Comment: To clarify: is it a requirement to persist *each step* to DynamoDB? Otherwise you could just use localStorage. Additionally, DynamoDB is basically the server in this instance. Maybe better terminology is "backend" (i.e. not the client).

Comment: Well let’s say a user gets to form 3, that means that there should be a single document in DynamoDB holding the data from form 1 and form 2 against the users email address.

Comment: Yes, but what's the behavior if they quit at step 2?

Comment: A single document in DynamoDB holding data from form 1.